# How handle rxdb .$.subscribe with replication

Tags: reactjs, subscribe, rxdb

i my case,

i m using myDatabase.collections.opportunities.$.subscribe(
that must save any historical step/changes for each. where there differences between documentData and previousDocumentData on "UPDATE" and "INSERT"

But im also using replicateRxCollection as it :

`.then(() => replicateRxCollection< OpportunityDetail, Checkpoint<OpportunityDetail> | undefined >({ collection: myDatabase.collections.opportunities, replicationIdentifier:` replication-of-opportunities`, retryTime: 10 * 1000,  deletedField: "_deleted", push: { batchSize: 5, handler: getPushHandler<OpportunityDetail>( "opportunities", "id", pushDocuments ), }, pull: { batchSize: 100, handler: getPullHandler<OpportunityDetail>( pullDocuments, "opportunities", "id", "updatedAt" ), }, }) )`

the fact is when the initial replication start (meaning user connexion and nothing inside collection before it, and rxdb insert data by using "INSERT"), the
myDatabase.collections.opportunities.$.subscribe(
compare previousDocumentData as [] to  documentData as [something] and create an historical step.

So how to handle that to dont set a new historical step each user connexion

i tried

- to add _replicated:boolean to all schemas, but it sucks as solution
- to compare updatedAt from 5mins ago, but it means we arr getting a
  time lack
- i try only accept `myDatabase.collections.opportunities.$.subscribe(async (changeEvent) => {if (changeEvent.operation === "UPDATE"){}` : but it means no historical for creation and its limiting my app on other things